# Getting I/O error while executing JUnit test case for Spring Controller

Tags: spring, rest, junit, controller, ioerror

I am executing a test case to call spring controller (GET method). However, It throws below I/O error.

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8039": Connect to localhost:8039 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8039 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:636)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
```

Below is the test case class that i am executing which throws the above error.

```
public class GetRuleSetsTests extends PreferencesAdminClientTestApplicationTests<GetRuleSetsResponse>{

    @Test
    public void testSuccess() throws Exception
    {
        final String mockedResponseJson = rawJsonFromFile("com/cnanational/preferences/client/rule-sets/getRuleSetsResponse.json");

        MockRestServiceServer mockServer = mockServer();

        mockServer.expect(requestTo(dummyUri()))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andExpect(queryParam("ruleSetDescription", "TestRuleDescription"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(
                        mockedResponseJson,
                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

        ServiceClientResponse<GetRuleSetsResponse> response = executeDummyRequest();

        mockServer.verify();

        assertThat(response.isSuccessful(), equalTo(true));

        GetRuleSetsResponse programResponse = response.getParsedResponseObject();

        assertThat(programResponse.getRuleSets().size(), equalTo(2));
    }
        @Override
    public URI dummyUri() {
        return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(baseUri())
                .path(this.endpointProperties.getRuleSets())
                .build()
                .toUri();
    }

}
```

What am i missing? Any inputs appreciated.

Comment: `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@RestClientTest` on your class in order to get the `MockRestServiceServer` configured

Comment: @UroshT. I have that annotation in parent class already still the error comes

Comment: Is it  `@RestClientTest(YourClassThatCallsTheMockServer.class)` ?

Comment: And show us the `executeDummyRequest()`, please

Comment: @ Urosh T

 protected RestTemplate restTemplate() {
  return this.restTemplateProvider.getRulesRestTemplate();
 }


 public ServiceClientResponse<GetRuleSetsResponse> executeDummyRequest() {
  return this.preferencesClientService.getRulesSets(
    "TestRuleDescription",
    TEST_USER_NAME,
    TEST_CORRELATION_ID,
    TEST_REQUESTOR_APP);
 }

 public URI dummyUri() {
  return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(baseUri())
    .path(this.endpointProperties.getRuleSets())
    .build()
    .toUri();
 }

Comment: But I can see similar test case passed with org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer$MockClientHttpRequestFactory, whereas the failing test case are using org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. I'm checking how to make use MockClientHttpRequestFactory. Please someone provide inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your test environment properly to run `MockRestServiceServer`

(by that, I mean `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@RestClientTest(ClassUnderTestThatCallsTheMockServer.class)`), make sure that you are not instantiating your mock server with `= new MockServer()`, instead just use an instance that is `@Autowired` from the spring context (because that instance is configured out of the box).

I see that you have a lot of inheritance and overridden methods in your tests, calling things with `this.returnSomething...`, so make sure that you are not instantiating things outside of the spring context.

Here is a simple example of a mock server to get some posts:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @RestClientTest(PostClient.class)
    public class PostClientMockTest {

        // class under test
        @Autowired
        private PostClient postClient;

        // autowired mock server from the spring context
        @Autowired
        private MockRestServiceServer mockRestServiceServer;

        @Test
        public void readPosts() throws Exception {

            String mockJsonResponse = "My response";

            mockRestServiceServer.expect(requestTo("https://myurl.com/posts?userId=1"))
                    .andRespond(withSuccess(mockJsonResponse, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8));

            List<Post> posts = postClient.readPosts(1);
            assertEquals(9, posts.size());
            mockRestServiceServer.verify();
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps